# How do I use travis encrypt to encrypt browserstack key?

Tags: travis-ci, browserstack, travis-ci-cli

I am having trouble getting my browserstack credentials to work on Travis. The credentials work locally if I don't encrypt the key and trigger the build from my local by just using environment variables.

I am using `travis encrypt`, which is instructed here: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/browserstack/ but I am not sure I am using it correctly and am having difficulty finding documentation on the command.

If my browserstack key is `foo`, should the command be:

`travis encrypt foo`

`travis encrypt BROWSERSTACK_ACCESS_KEY=foo`

`travis encrypt BROWSERSTACK_ACCESS_KEY="foo"`

or something else? I am using the output of the command and putting it at the end of my `.travis.yml` like so:

```
addons:
  browserstack:
    username: "myusername"
    access_key:
      secure: "encryptedkey"
```

But I am consistently getting `Browserstack access_key is invalid.` in my Travis build.

Comment: Based on the documentation, if your browserstack key is foo, you should be using travis encrypt "foo"

Comment: The third command you described, `travis encrypt BROWSERSTACK_ACCESS_KEY="foo"`, looks correct. Not sure why it is failing for you, though.

Answer (score 1):

Since Travis uses bash to evaluate this (iirc) you should use single quotes instead as bash will not expand special characters within single quotes. And you could probably also wrap the whole thing in double quotes for good measure, so this should work:

```
travis encrypt "BROWSERSTACK_ACCESS_KEY='foo'"
```

Also, if I understand your use of this secret correctly you should do something like this instead to configure the addon:

```
secure: "$BROWSERSTACK_ACCESS_KEY"
```